# How to retrieve data from local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, local-storage

i have a class called ui and after saving data in local storage using save method it works but when i'm getting the data with loadData method it gives me undefined .. i want to know why ?!!

```
class UI{ 

 save(key, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
 }

 getValue(key) {
  localStorage.getItem(key);
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: During `getValue` you're not actually doing anything with the result. You either want to `return localStorage.getItem(key)` it or assign it to a property of `UI` to be accessed by your app.

As @kunuos pointed out, you can make both methods `static` methods if `UI` is simply a utility to be used by other modules, and additionally that you probably want to stringify values before saving them.

Comment: thanks a lot right I'm not returning the value that cases me undefined instead

Comment: please another question, when I'm retrieving data using getValue() and binding its value variable in the constructor method inside the class it returns an empty array however there are data in local storage, please take a look at the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/cj3s69xa/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what's the `value` you are saving to the `localStorage`. If it's not a primitive data type, you'd need to convert the value into a string before you save it in the `localStorage` using the `JSON.stringify(value)` method and when you run `getvalue` you'd want to parse the stringified value using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))`.

PS: using static methods make sense when you are trying to save or retrieve data to/from the localStorage. Giving access to individual objects to have access to localStorage might cause problems in the future.

Comment: I'm saving a primitive value and tried to parse the result but also gives me undefined

Comment: Could you paste in some code or share a screenshot of your code